# Eventbrite API - List only upcoming events - PHP

Tags: php, eventbrite

I am looking for a way to only display upcoming events in php.

The is the code I am using which displays all events.

```
include "../../libraries/eventbrite/eventbrite.php"; 

$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => '***',
                               'user_key' => '***');
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

$events = $eb_client->user_list_events();

Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow');
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: The code above displays all events including past events which there are hundreds. I would like to only display upcoming events. And if possible filter these down a bit more by Event Type.

I have been testing this code in its own php file in my Drupal theme's directory. Would this also work in the page.tpl file?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display 'live' events then you need to pass in the event_status parameter as so:

```
$event_params = array( //pass these args through the user_list_events to only get live events
  'event_statuses' => 'live,started'
);

$events = $eb_client->user_list_events($event_params);
```